# Как менять цены в зависимости от количества товара в таблице?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Помогите решить проблему, т.к. я ещё новичок в `js и jquery`. У меня есть таблица с товаром. В этой таблице можно будет менять количество товара. Рядом должна меняться цена. Проблема в том, что мне необходимо, чтобы цена менялась только в нужной мне строке, не могу добиться этого. Код прикладываю:

Ниже приведён пример на изменение количества товара:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.minus').click(function() {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 1;
    count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
    $input.val(count);
    $input.change();
    return false;
  });
  $('.plus').click(function(op) {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
    $input.change();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center">
  <tbody>
    <th>наименование</th>
    <th>количество</th>
    <th>цена</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Товар первый</td>
      <td>
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <input type="text" size="3" id="QUANTITY_INPUT" name="QUANTITY_INPUT" min="0" step="0" oninput="set_quant();" max="0" value="1" />
        <span class="plus">+</span>
      </td>
      <td><span id="count_price"> 0 </span><span> руб.</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Товар второй</td>
      <td>
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <input type="text" size="3" id="QUANTITY_INPUT" name="QUANTITY_INPUT" min="0" step="0" oninput="set_quant();" max="0" value="1" />
        <span class="plus">+</span>
      </td>
      <td><span id="count_price"> 0 </span><span> руб.</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Свой код на изменение цены пока не выкладываю, т.к. у меня неправильно меняется (либо в одном месте, либо не в том). Цена должна меняться в той строке, где изменено количество, т.е. в строке `<span> с id="count_price"`

Помогите, пожалуйста, новичку.

Comment: Очень странно получается. Наверное, код изменения количества не вы писали?

Comment: Цену можно для примера взять так: 
      var goods_price = "102";
      var sum_price = goods_price * $input.val();
Далее испытываю сложности в правильном написании кода... 
Написать код в функции с событием click или иначе, затрудняюсь ответить...
Пробовал разные решения, добавляется то сразу во все строки с Id="count_price", то в нужной строке, но не в том месте))

Comment: код на изменение товара писал не я. Взят на просторах интернета. Я только еще учусь этому ремеслу

Comment: Ни кто и никогда не говорил  или  нигде не читал, что идентификатор `id` у элемента может быть один единственный  и у разных элементов не может быть одинаковый `id`

Comment: это да, скопировал, не исправив id  на class. Все верно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот один из способов менять цену при изменении количества.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function change($tr, val) {
    var $input = $tr.find('.quantity');
    var count = parseInt($input.val()) + val;
    count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
    $input.val(count);
    var $price = $tr.find('.count_price');
    $price.text(count * $price.data('price'));
  }
  $('.minus').click(function() {
    change($(this).closest('tr'), -1);
  });
  $('.plus').click(function() {
    change($(this).closest('tr'), 1);
  });
  $('.quantity').on("input", function() {
    var $price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.count_price');
    $price.text(this.value * $price.data('price'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>наименование</th>
      <th>количество</th>
      <th>цена</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Товар первый</td>
      <td>
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <input class="quantity" type="text" size="3" min="0" step="0" max="0" value="1" />
        <span class="plus">+</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="count_price" data-price="250"> 250 </span><span> руб.</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Товар второй</td>
      <td>
        <span class="minus">-</span>
        <input class="quantity" type="text" size="3" min="0" step="0" max="0" value="1" />
        <span class="plus">+</span>
      </td>
      <td><span class="count_price" data-price="100"> 100 </span><span> руб.</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как раз то, что нужно! Через поиск тоже пробовал, но из-за нехватки знаний и опыта ничего не получалось! Спасибо еще раз

Comment: цена меняется только при клике, но для полноты еще бы хотелось  повесить событие, которое автоматически меняет цену после того, как мы ввели значение в поле input. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: @Alexandr обновил ответ. Я бы вам посоветовал сначала пытаться самому разобраться, а потом уже спрашивать. Потому что иначе вы далеко не уйдете.

Comment: я с вами полностью согласен, но на примерах мне как-то всё же проще... Вы написали тот код, я его разобрал, сейчас экспериментирую. Если вам всё же не сложно, напишите мне пример...

Comment: @Alexandr я ответ уже обновил, там меняется цена, когда в `input` значение меняем.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое еще раз! Мне есть с кого брать пример) Буду учиться